# What can be done to this code to look and work in true async way?

Tags: c#, async-await

So I am building a small server app that launches some amount of TCP clients and then starts recieving connections from them. The problem is that the clients are launching separately and with strict timing between launches (well, they are external programs with c# addin code in them). So I need to start recieving connections before all clients are able to connect. I wrote a test program and it is working but it doesn't feel and look too async-y. Can I somehow run WorkFlowRunAsync() only once?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class Program
    {
        static async Task WorkFlowRunAsync()
        {
            while (true)//listener infinite loop
            {
                Console.WriteLine("workflow");
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
            }
        }
        static async Task SpecialRunAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("special task");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        }
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            WorkFlowRunAsync();
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)//exact 6 clients launch
            {
                await SpecialRunAsync();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationTokenSource.Token);//here is the delay between launches
            }
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            await WorkFlowRunAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var the_loop = WorkFlowRunAsync();` `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { ... }` `await the_loop;`?

Comment: ^^ In words: `WorkFlowRunAsync` returns a `Task`. You can assign it to a var and await it later.

Comment: Unrelated: I'd give it a CancellationToken parameter as stopping token, so you can replace `while(true)` with `while(!stopToken.IsCancellationRequested)` -> makes for a more friendly and clean shutdown.

Comment: Are you sure that using raw TCP is the best approach for your application? There are plenty of higher level Inter Process Communication protocols that are well designed and tested.

Comment: You should probably also show your real code. Your example is very "async-y", but it does not do anything, so there is no telling if the behavior is "correct".

Comment: I am not that proficient in C#, so I don't know better. I lurked that virtual file stuff a little, but mine method also works via network. May be RabbitMQ is the best for this, but I realised it after I had made all the work. The question itself is sinthetic on purpose, just to understand the technology. I totally agree that the current code is a mess, but it is a working mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow run WorkFlowRunAsync() only once?

Sure!

One nice thing about `async`/`await` in modern languages is that the asynchronous methods return a promise (in this case, `Task`), and that promise is actually an object *just like any other object*. You *can* `await` it right away (and most code does do that), but you don't *have* to. Since the `Task` is just an object instance, you can also store it in a variable and `await` it later:

```
static async Task Main()
{
  var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  Task workflowTask = WorkFlowRunAsync();
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)//exact 6 clients launch
  {
    await SpecialRunAsync();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationTokenSource.Token);//here is the delay between launches
  }
  cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
  await workflowTask;
}
```